# How do you say "hangover" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi bezonas ĉi tiun vorton hodiaŭ...

Comment: Let me check for you: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/search?q=hangover

Comment: Be sure to check a dictionary before asking.

Answer (score 3):

I believe people usually say *postebrio*.

Feliĉan novjaron!

Answer (score 0):

Mi estas postebria. I am hungover.

Mi havas postebrian kapdoloron. I have a hangover.